# Shortest recommended length of stainless steel tubing between fittings

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Just a quick poll to anybody with experience putting together stainless steel tubing.  I have two swagelok fittings for 1/16" stainless steel tubing (0.02" thick), and just wanted to know what the minimum length of tube between fittings is (NOT including the length of tube inside the compression sleeves of the fittings themselves).  My guesstimate is that somewhere around half an inch of metal tube showing between the fittings is probably as short as you'd want to go.

Any best practices or recommendations based upon experience?

Thanks!

Comment: I leave a few fitting-lengths extra, just in case a fitting needs to be replaced so you can easily cut the tube.

Comment: Oh I've seen (larger) swagelok's nearly back-to-back, but that's a last resort IMO. Severely limits ability to work on it, as you can imagine - can't disassemble without rotating everything attached to one of the ends. I agree with your instinct, do leave yourself extra breathing room, more is better. Think thru what kinds of out-of-order disassembly you might want to do in the future. Besides that, half inch seems workable, maybe if the stuff you're connecting on the two ends isn't perfectly coaxial, add extra to let the 1/16" bend to take up the overconstraint. // PS I like jko's comment

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!